# box .Net v2 API how to fetch all fields?

Tags: box-api

The Box v2 REST API appears to contain methods that return "full objects".  That is, they return all the fields and properties of the object requested with one "simple" call.

When trying the official .Net SDK, it appears that if you don't specify fields by name in the "FoldersManager" or "FilesManager" (for example), you get minimal details of the objects returned.

Is there a way to make the request return **all** fields/properties?  I realize maybe ItemsCollection is one you'd want to retrieve specifically, but the rest should really be included in one call (like the REST capability).

Thanks for any ideas!

-AJ

Answer (score 1):

If no fields are specified in the request, the default fields are returned in the response (ie. what the API decides is the most commonly used fields). If a field is specified the API returns all required fields along with the specified fields (usually type, id, and etag).

There is currently no simple flag that will return all fields as this would likely be abused out of convenience. The only way to return all fields is to manually specify all of the fields you are looking for. If using any of the official SDKs, these fields names can usually be found in the object models

HTH